# select every top 1 row and 100th row value from table with 10000 rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has 10000 plus rows. I am trying to select the value of every top 1 and top 100th row that has where clause and dividing the table by 100 in the loop.

Ex is shown in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: So you would like to have row 1, 100, 200, 300, 400? Do you have some specific ordering attribute you can use (for instance the id)?

Comment: Can you explain how the requirement in the question's text produces the output you've shared?

Comment: what query did you try so far? what the issue you are facing?

Comment: @derpirscher yes, you are right, I am trying to other operations with the table and I want to break down that table into small bits with min and max id. And yes I have the ordering attribute.

Comment: @Jayendran I am using a while loop with the start value as top 1 of the table, but I am not sure how to get the next top value that is exactly next 100th value even if the reference id is not consecutive because I have a where clause.

Comment: @ArunPrasath Please post your code in your Question. It's difficult for all to give the suggestions without seeing the query what actually you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
select t.refid, lead(t.refid) over (order by refid) as next_refid
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by refid) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum % 100 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks bunch for the script. It helped to get it done.